# SSH requires authentication with keys

Tags: ssh

I am quite puzzled as to why ssh requires password Authentication although i have generated and copies keys.

I installed Ubuntu mini 14.04, and for whatever the reason I am not able to connect to it without a password via SSH.

At first I believed it was an issue with the guest machine which generated and copied the keys, however that is not the case. Here is what I have done.
Machine A (Let’s call it Client), Machine B (Ubuntu Mini, let’s call it Server). Somehow what to do on which machine gets a little confusing on many of the instructions I have found.

1. Delete all entries in /home/user/.ssh on both the Client and the Server (making sure it was all clean)

On Client

1. Generated keys ssh-keygen on the client, went through the questions and did not apply a password.
2. Copied keys to server ssh-copy-id username@192.168.1.2 - entered password.
3. SSH’d into server, client machine prompt for password, I check the make sure the key had been copied over the server. It was listed in the servers /home/users/.ssh/authorized_keys file
4. I checked permission on /home/user/.ssh folder and made sure it was 700

SSH always requires a password.

I repeated the same process on the server and was able to auto login via ssh to the client.

**SSH Directory on Server**

```
    username@Server:~$ ls -ld .ssh
    drwx------ 2 username username 4096 Oct 27 08:24 .ssh
```

**.SSH Directory Contents on Server**

```
    username@Server:~/.ssh$ ls -l
    total 16
    -rw------- 1 username username 789 Oct 26 21:08 authorized_keys
    -rw------- 1 username username 1675 Oct 26 20:37 id_rsa
    -rw-r--r-- 1 username username 400 Oct 26 20:37 id_rsa.pub
    -rw-r--r-- 1 username username 222 Oct 26 20:37 known_hosts
```

**Authorized Keys on Server**

```
    username@Server:~/.ssh$ cat authorized_keys
    ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQDJKqmBuPPxzFx/opVJhNQNiUUHLQIT4n2ScQljni489ONzUXmTC8fAhGprDFUhVs GZrlFm+RJrmu5VlasG+dLG33Y7mXTnhsj5FVjUzbbliUbVqizR di18Gh6AM5VyiSqSh/prDmT5xpasQLQopGmB3kxCP6+6RnKnovUk8f4UOs4i0HXZM9VM EnwgPkN9v6LTTI7VI2QApLl/c1aYfMF2jOua/T7Xw4hdz+DbzEQi8ygk9NYpbE1QB8l4TB2Ls6hwBEVlSeHcP3H 6RX8a71ow+qGz5Zz9cK5Eg6v3OKK6YXcwS2osePWgMmJsNW/mVgne3pQvoajIZyMx9+r9mCIF pi@PiScanner
```

**RSA Public keys on Client**

```
     pi@PiScanner ~/.ssh $ cat id_rsa.pub
        ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQDJKqmBuPPxzFx/opVJhNQNiUUHLQIT4n2ScQljni489ONzUXmTC8fAhGprDFUhVs GZrlFm+RJrmu5VlasG+dLG33Y7mXTnhsj5FVjUzbbliUbVqizR di18Gh6AM5VyiSqSh/prDmT5xpasQLQopGmB3kxCP6+6RnKnovUk8f4UOs4i0HXZM9VM EnwgPkN9v6LTTI7VI2QApLl/c1aYfMF2jOua/T7Xw4hdz+DbzEQi8ygk9NYpbE1QB8l4TB2Ls6hwBEVlSeHcP3H 6RX8a71ow+qGz5Zz9cK5Eg6v3OKK6YXcwS2osePWgMmJsNW/mVgne3pQvoajIZyMx9+r9mCIF pi@PiScanner
```

**pi@PiScanner ~/.ssh $ ssh -vvv username@192.168.101.2**

```
OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4+deb7u2, OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.101.2 [192.168.101.2] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug3: Incorrect RSA1 identifier
debug3: Could not load "/home/pi/.ssh/id_rsa" as a RSA1 public key
debug1: identity file /home/pi/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: Checking blacklist file /usr/share/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: Checking blacklist file /etc/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: identity file /home/pi/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/pi/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/pi/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/pi/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/pi/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.3 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4+deb7u2
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "192.168.101.2" from file "/home/pi/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type ECDSA in file /home/pi/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh...01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp52 1-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-excha nge-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh...01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.c om,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.c om,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cb c,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cb c,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-256-96,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-512-96,hmac-ripemd160,hmac -ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-256-96,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-512-96,hmac-ripemd160,hmac -ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha2 56,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@o penssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@o penssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-e...tm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@op enssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1, umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh...60@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-e...tm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@op enssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1, umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh...60@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ECDSA 73:78:68:3b:58:0d:78:a9:64:96:6e:9c:ca:0c:ae:9f
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "192.168.101.2" from file "/home/pi/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type ECDSA in file /home/pi/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug1: Host '192.168.101.2' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/pi/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct
debug2: kex_derive_keys
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: /home/pi/.ssh/id_rsa (0x782a3308)
debug2: key: /home/pi/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/pi/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil))
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password
debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/pi/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /home/pi/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/pi/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/pi/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/pi/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred: ,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
username@192.168.101.2's password:
```

Cannot get this to auto log in!  any assistance would be greatful! thank you.

Comment: please, post log from server, which contains the reason for rejecting your key. It should be `/var/log/auth.log`

Comment: you mention "public key on client", client must use **private** key.

Comment: Private fails also     auth.log https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/58850968/auth.log  i notice two itemd sshd[1729]: Authentication refused: bad ownership or modes for directory /home/ylafont  and  constant pam_windfind erros

Answer (score 1):

Possible cause: is your id_rsa file corrupted?

I see these lines in the log that look suspicious:

```
debug3: Incorrect RSA1 identifier
debug3: Could not load "/home/pi/.ssh/id_rsa" as a RSA1 public key
```

I have no such message when I do an ssh connection...

Comment: i have generated the id_rsa file several times  in trying to fix this issue.  i cannot be corrupt

Answer (score 1):

Solved!  The permissions to `/home/username` must also be set to 744.  This is not very clear anywhere I looked.

Comment: I'm almost 1000% certain that those are *not* permissions you want to set on a directory.